# Copying iterators in Python

Tags: python, iterator, copy

When you make a (shallow) copy of an iterator, it returns a new iterator.

```py
from copy import copy


data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

iter1 = iter(data)
iter2 = copy(iter1)

[i for i in iter1]    #[1, 2, 3, 4]
[i for i in iter2]    #[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

When you make a shallow copy of an iterator created with itertools, it returns the same iterator, but deepcopy returns a new one.

```py
from copy import copy, deepcopy
from itertools import takewhile


data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

iter1 = takewhile(lambda x: x < 5, data)
iter2 = copy(iter1)
iter3 = deepcopy(iter1)

[i for i in iter1]    #[1, 2, 3, 4]
[i for i in iter2]    #[] because it's the same iterator
[i for i in iter3]    #[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is this the expected behavior? Nowhere in the documentation did I find any information about copying iterators. I know that there is an itertools.tee() function, but its usability is limited (e.g. when we iterate over a changing collection).

Comment: This is expected behavior.

Comment: Presumably each iterator would be implemented differently. I notice that you can't copy generators this way, as an additional note.

Comment: Incidentally, `copy` does not return the same iterator object for `takewhile`: `iter1 is iter2` is false.

Comment: The `copy` module isn't designed very safely.

Comment: Also, no, that's not the same iterator. It's a half-functional copy you can't use independently because the copy was too shallow to make sense - it doesn't have its own copy of the underlying iterator over `data`.

Comment: Why is `itertools.tee()` not suitable?  I think iterating over a changing correction leads to unspecified behavior in any case.

Answer (score 2):

This is known behavior.  An iterator is stateful: the current location is the state. So it makes sense that a shallow copy shares that state, as in the example you show.

A spec for "Copyable iterators" was actually discussed in a PEP way [back in 2003](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0323/).

They pointed out that "'support' for [separately iterably] `copy.copy` in a user-coded iterator type is almost invariably 'accidental'.... [T]he copy will be independently iterable with respect to the original only if" certain conditions exist in the implementation.

They decided *not* to adopt that PEP.

Comment: So what's the correct assumption about copying iterators? Because from what I understand, it is not officially supported. But on the other hand, we have functions in a standard library that do this. For example, in dataclasses, the asdict() and astuple() functions create a deepcopy of an object attributes which one can be an iterator.

Comment: An iterator is stateful: the current location is the state. So  it makes sense that a shallow copy shares that state, as in the example you show.